How to use SOCKS in Chrome, via selenium?
import time
import imaplib
import email
import json
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
import random
import pyautogui
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from white_list import *
from win32api import SetCursorPos


profile_path = r"C:\Users\expin\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data"
profile_name = "Profile 1"

def click(x,y):
    mouse = Controller()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    mouse.position = (x, y+random.randint(1,2))
    # mouse.press(Button.left)
    # mouse.release(Button.left)



# ((((((((((((((((((((((((----------        DATA        ----------)))))))))))))))))))))))) #



New_User_Data = {
    "38.170.252.127:9615:Username:Password" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36",
}

for trynna in New_User_Data:

    user_agent = New_User_Data[trynna]
    result = trynna.split(':')
    proxy_url = f"https://{result[2]}:{result[3]}@{result[0]}:{result[1]}"

    seleniumwire_options = {
        "proxy": {
            "http": proxy_url,
            "https": proxy_url
        },
    }



    options = Options()
    # options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={profile_path}")
    # options.add_argument(f"--profile-directory={profile_name}")
    options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    # options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    # options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    options.add_argument("--enable-unsafe-swiftshader")
    options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
    options.add_argument("--start-fullscreen")
    # options.add_argument("--incognito")
    # options.add_argument("--headless=new")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
        seleniumwire_options=seleniumwire_options,
        options=options
    )

    # driver.get("https://httpbin.io/ip")
    # print(driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "body").text)

    driver.get("https://www.tiktok.com")
    time.sleep(2)


# ####################################################################################


    with open("tiktok_cookies.json", "r") as file:
        cookies = json.load(file)

    for cookie in cookies:
        driver.add_cookie(cookie)

    driver.refresh()



    input("Press Enter to close the browser...")
    driver.quit()

I use HTTPS, but the one I bought is very slow. And I also have SOCKS proxies, already tested by many proxies with fast speed.
But no matter how I try to use them in Chrome via Selenium, there is always the same problem. I don't know how to use SOCKS which has a login and password. I will be grateful!!!!
